# Hiding database expert and table explorer in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to hide the database expert and table explorer when sharing a report with someone?  in other words user who runs the report just need to use the select expert or parameter field programmed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give the user one of the 3rd-party viewers. See list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers).